# What is the command line to inspect the IPv6 discovery cache?

Tags: ipv6

I can't seem to find a command for this, only configuration commands are listed in the documentation and **show ipv6 nd destination** does not work on my system

This is on Cisco vIOS 15.2

Edit:  rfc2461-Regardless of the specific implementation, it is critical that the Neighbor Cache entry for a router is shared by all Destination Cache entries using that router in order to prevent redundant Neighbor Unreachability Detection probes. "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command you're looking for is `show ipv6 neighbors`:

```
box#show ipv6 neighbors
IPv6 Address                              Age Link-layer Addr State Interface
FE80::222:8303:4977:5A95                    0 0022.8377.5a95  REACH Gi0/0/1.841
```

Comment: I knew about this command but I thought I was missing something. Very few results were returned by Google when I searched the above command (show ipv6 nd destinations). Not sure why this is still in the command index since it is not used an it have never been used (I assume that because I can not find any references )

Comment: It was introduced in 15.0 "Use the show ipv6 nd destination command to display information about IPv6 host-mode destination cache entries." WHat aret hey referring to when they say host mode? ipv6 routing disabled?

Comment: I think that there is more to this and the answer provided is not correct http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios-xml/ios/15-0se/features/ip6-strict-host-mode.pdf  The command that I was asking about has something to do with IPv6 in host mode and only then you can probably use the command that I was looking for

Comment: In that case, please edit your question to clarify what exactly it is you want to know.

Comment: The question is correct, what is incorrect there? I am still digging the topic but I suspect that the destination cache does not exist on a router with routing enabled but it does exist when the router is in host mode (see command ipv6 nd host mode strict)

Comment: Here is more from rfc2461:  Regardless of the specific implementation, it is    critical that the Neighbor Cache entry for a router is shared by all
   Destination Cache entries using that router in order to prevent
   redundant Neighbor Unreachability Detection probes. "  So the command you posted inspects the neighbor chache...